# What document contentTypes does Chrome render as monospaced HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, mime-types, content-type

Some Chrome URLs are just text files that are rendered as monospaced text files.
As an example, this is the Public Suffix List (https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat), and looks like this:

[image: Public Suffix List]

You can also get to this type of page by going to any raw GitHub user content, like https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/docs/main/README.md.

This is the HTML wrapper I see for these type of monospaced text documents:

```html
<html data-lt-installed="true">
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
    "Lots of text!"
    </pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

Some `contentType` values predictably get rendered in this HTML. `image/png` does not get rendered this way, but `text/css` and `text/js` do. Additionally, `application/json` also gets rendered in this way, like https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json.

#### Question

For which `document.contentType` values does *Chrome* render this monospaced text content with this HTML wrapper?

Comment: Most likely any response that has `Content-Type: text/plain` response header

Comment: I doubt there's any definitive list, and it can probably change due to other extensions. E.g. before Chrome did this itself, there was an extension that added color to View Source.

Comment: @Justinas https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json has no content-type response header, and yet is rendered in this way.

Comment: "I doubt there's any definitive list" => That's my question. Stackoverflow is a large repository of community documentation. If this behavior is not explicitly documented, then this is a perfect place for this question to be.

Comment: I see that https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json actually has Content-Type header set to `application/json` when using Postman

Comment: That's my mistake. I was using firefox and the resource was cached, which did not report a content-type response header. My point still stands that it's not just a `Content-Type: text/plain` response header.